# How can I edit the content of a ini file?

Tags: php, arrays, string, file

I would like to be able to edit a config file for a server application using php. The config file is as follows:

```
include=sc_serv_public.conf
streamid_2=2
streampath_2=/relay
streamrelayurl_2=http://<full_url_of_relay_including_port>
;allowrelay=0
;allowpublicrelay=0
```

I would like to edit the line:

```
streamrelayurl_2=http://<full_url_of_relay_including_port>
```

and then save the file.

I am currently using:

```
$data = file_get_contents("sc_serv.conf"); //read the file
$convert = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line
```

to open the file, but now I dont know how to edit it.

Comment: What is your question? And how in the world does this have two upvotes?

Comment: Iterate over the $convert array until you find the line that starts with "streamrelayurl_2=", then update that element to the value you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you could just use `file()` instead. This just loads it up into array form, no need to `explode`. Then after that, you just loop the elements, if the desired needle is found, overwrite it, the write the file again:

```
$data = file('sc_serv.conf', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // load file into an array
$find = 'streamrelayurl_2='; // needle
$new_value = 'http://www.whateverurl.com'; // new value
foreach($data as &$line) {
    if(strpos($line, 'streamrelayurl_2=') !== false) { // if found
        $line = $find . $new_value; // overwrite
        break; // stop, no need to go further
    }
}
file_put_contents('sc_serv.conf', implode("\n", $data)); // compound into string again and write
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file()` to read the file content to an array, then you can iterate trough the array with `foreach()` searching with the `strstr()` function the line that have your URL (in this case is in the var `$id_change`) and change the value. Then as you found what you needed, you end the `foreach()` with `break`. And make your string to save in the file with `implode()` and save the string to the config file with `file_put_content()`.

See the code:

```
<?php

$new_url = 'http://www.google.com';
$id_change = 'streamrelayurl_2';
$file = "sc_serv.conf";

$data = file($file); //read the file

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
  if(strstr($value, $id_change)) {
    $info = $id_change . '=' . $new_url . "\n";
    $data[$key] = $info;
    break;  
  }     
}   

$data = implode("", $data);

file_put_contents($file, $data);

?>
```

Output:

```
include=sc_serv_public.conf
streamid_2=2
streampath_2=/relay
streamrelayurl_2=http://www.google.com
;allowrelay=0
;allowpublicrelay=0
```

Comment: @meun5 you got some advance?